# Object selection in opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new to 3D programming and have been playing around with OpenGL ES for Android for a little while now and I've seen some options of this questions beaning ray tracking/tracing and Object Picking and something about using the pixels to select 3D Objects. I'm trying to make something like a paint program with OpenGL ES for Android to where I can select a line from a cube and delete it or objects to be deleted or modified. Anyway, I'm unsure of where to start learning this I've tried Google and didn't really find anything helpful. Maybe if there's a video tutorial or a website that explains this better or any help to point me in the direction to go would be very grateful. Thank you so much in advanced.

Yes I know this is a possible duplicate Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an iOS dev myself, but I recently implemented ray casting for my game, so I'll try to answer this in a platform agnostic way.

There are two steps to the ray-casting operation: firstly, you need to get the ray from the user's tap, and secondly, you need to test the triangles defining your model for intersections. Note that this requires you to still have them in memory or be able to recover them -- you can't just be keeping them in a vbo on the graphics card.

First, the conversion to world coordinates. Since you are no doubt using a projection matrix to get a 3-D perspective for your models, you need to **unproject** the point to get it in world coordinates. There are many libraries with this already implemented, such as glut's glunproject which I believe are available on Android. I believe that mathematically this amounts to taking the inverse of all the transformations which are currently acting on your models. Regardless, there are many implementations publicly available online you can copy from.

At this point, you are going to need a Z coordinate for the point you are trying to unproject. You actually want to unproject twice, once with a Z coord of 0 and once with a Z coord of 1. The vector which results from the z-Coord of 0 is the origin of the ray, and by subtracting this vector from your z-coord of 1 vector you will get the direction. Now you are ready to test for intersections of your model's polygons.

I have had success with the method presented in this paper (http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf) for doing the actual intersection test. The algorithm is implemented in C at the end, but you should be able to convert it to Java with little trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the info I'm going to try it out and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

The selection features of OpenGL are not available with OpenGL ES, so you would have to build that yourself.

I recommend starting with OpenGL ES sample programs that are specific to Android. I think this article will help:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1